# how to get erc20 token balance using web3

Tags: web3js

I am still new with web3

How can I get balance of token?

On ropsten network, I have 100 LINK token.

Below is my code

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const rpcURL = 'https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/xxxx'
const web3 = new Web3(rpcURL)

let tokenAddress = "0x20fe562d797a42dcb3399062ae9546cd06f63280";
let walletAddress = "0xdD440e8eCA5F1F3e6D5ffE903148EFB374942df2";

// The minimum ABI to get ERC20 Token balance
let minABI = [
  // balanceOf
  {
    "constant":true,
    "inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],
    "name":"balanceOf",
    "outputs":[{"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],
    "type":"function"
  },
  // decimals
  {
    "constant":true,
    "inputs":[],
    "name":"decimals",
    "outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],
    "type":"function"
  }
];

let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(minABI,tokenAddress);
async function getBalance() {
  balance = await contract.methods.balanceOf(walletAddress);
  return balance;
}

console.log(getBalance());
```

The code return:

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

based on my search on google, this promise pending should be solved by using async function but in my case, it still showing promise pending.

I am using latest node 14 and web3.js 1.26

Comment: The code returns blank output because you're not printing anything. Looks like you're new not only to web3.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to print out with console log. what i mean in my question is, i have trouble with the promise pending although i have used async function. perhaps you can point out my mistake. thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change this:

```
balance = await contract.methods.balanceOf(walletAddress);
```

To this:

```
balance = await contract.methods.balanceOf(walletAddress).call();
```

And this:

```
console.log(getBalance());
```

To this if you're using web3.js v0.x:

```
getBalance().then(function (result) {
    console.log(result.toFixed());
});
```

Or to this if you're using web3.js v1.x:

```
getBalance().then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: i updated my code, but it return a long list of methods.

Comment: @webmaster: Sorry, please see updated answer.

Comment: it said

getBalance().call().then(function (result) {
             ^

TypeError: getBalance(...).call is not a function

Comment: @webmaster: Sorry, please see updated answer.